# Jquery sliding boxes not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

My Jquery code doesn't seem to work in IE8 when adding a doctype above my html tag.

Maybe there's a way to restructure these codes to have it working in ie8.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //Caption Sliding (Partially Hidden to Visible)
            $('.boxgrid.caption').hover(function(){
                $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
            }, function() {
                $(".cover", this).stop().animate({top:'161px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
            });
        });


The website can be seen here:
```

http://www.keencloudmedia.com/sample/test.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Doesn't seem to work"_? Could you perhaps say what is supposed to happen and what actually happens? (Do you get errors in the console? Does nothing at all happen? Does something happen but it's the wrong thing?)

Comment: Could you show us the html or/and the error?

Comment: P.S. Is this the same issue as [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11200287/615754)?

Comment: Post the relevant CSS and HTML code also.
And also tell us the exact error[if any] you are getting.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Here's the link: http://www.keencloudmedia.com/sample/test.html. Click on the "see more" button and there you'll see the sliding boxes where I'm having an issue with IE8. Thanks!

Comment: @nnnnnn let me reiterate that - "it seems to work differently in IE8". You can check it out in the link above and click on the "see more" button where you will find the sliding boxes. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.boxgrid.caption').mouseenter(function(){
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({'top':'0px'},160);
        });
        $('.boxgrid.caption').mouseleave(function() {
            $(".cover", this).stop().animate({'top':'161px'},160);
        });
    });
```

and you can use this meta tag (works with jquery excellent)

```
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: Hi Barlas. Thank you for your feedback. But that meta tag is already in my html file. You can check it in this link: http://www.keencloudmedia.com/sample/test.html. Please click on the "see more" button and that's where the sliding boxes are. Check the difference between Firefox and IE8. Its really hell for me. lol

Comment: Hi Barlas. you can find the site here :) http://www.keencloudmedia.com/sample/test.html. Click on the "see more" button and there's the sliding boxes which has the jquery codes above. I hope you can test it on IE8. :) Thanks!

Comment: you need to correct your css  this is your CSS .caption .boxcaption { top: 161; left: 0; } you need to put px at the and of 161. like this =>  top:161px

Comment: Barlas! It worked! Thank you so much! :) I wish I could vote up but I need 15 reputation to do this for you. Just a newbie here:) Thanks again!