# jQuery: animating backgroundPosition behaves oddly in IE < 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

Try hovering over the "Cancel" button in Internet Explorer 8:

http://jsfiddle.net/HYDKa/

You'll notice that the first time you hover over it, it jumps and you can see the "OK" button, but then it corrects itself. Subsequent hovers function normally, though.

Please note that this bug also occurs with the "OK" button; it's just more obvious with the "Cancel" button. Also, this bug is present in IE 6 and 7, but the demo I've provided won't work since the image is Base64 encoded.

The code works fine in non-IE browsers, of course.

Is this a jQuery bug? Is there anything I can do to work around it besides splitting the images up? I could include a stylesheet for IE < 9, but I'd rather not if I don't have to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7719214/jquery-animate-background-position/8026020#8026020), I ended up resolving my issue by changing "backgroundPosition" to "background-position-x". Also, since some browsers don't support "background-position-x", I created CSS3 transitions to do the same thing and then wrapped the JavaScript code in an if statement so that it only runs if the browser doesn't support CSS3 transitions. I wasn't using feature detection anywhere else on my website and I didn't want to bother with Modernizr for such a simple thing, so I used the function shown [here](http://tobint.com/blog/detecting-css3-transition-support/). One other thing I should note is that I didn't end up needing to bother with the "sliding_link_original_background_position" variable at all.

I appreciate barlasapaydin's time as well as the time of anybody else who read this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

old internet explorer versions wont accept CSS values without 'px'. example= width:10px;

so you need to add + 'px' at the end of animate values.

[Here is working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HYDKa/2/)

```
    $(this).find('.sliding_link_image').animate({
        'backgroundPosition': (sliding_link_original_background_position + 10) + 'px'//<--here
    }, 150);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.sliding_link_image').animate({
        'backgroundPosition': sliding_link_original_background_position + 'px'//<--and here
    }, 150);
```

Comment: It looks like the bug is still there. Did you try your code in Internet Explorer 8?

Comment: I just now tried your link again in IE 8 and it definitely doesn't work. Remember that the bug only happens the first time you hover over the buttons. After that, they work normally. If you're certain that your link works in IE 8, may I ask which version of Windows you're running?

Comment: windows 7.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200515/jquery-sliding-boxes-not-working-in-ie8/11203650#11203650 read comments mate, same problem here too.. maybe ur browser is bugged /:

Comment: [Here](http://i.imgur.com/BKa8i.png) is a screenshot of your code not working in IE 8 on Windows XP. I've also tried it in IE 8 on Windows 7 and it didn't work in that environment either.

Comment: m8 ur os is really old /: sorry coudnt help ://

Comment: mate i guess; your os or your ie, is bugged .. cuz its just working fine on my computer.. this is screenshot on ie7 = http://i.imgur.com/ZBZNq.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. IE 9 emulating IE 7 is not the same as IE 7. See [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/10865/how-can-i-test-my-web-site-in-ie6-ie7-ie8-and-ie9#comment22637_10876), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249454/how-well-does-ie7-8-mode-in-ie9-compare-to-actually-running-ie7-8) and [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?707108-IE9-Beta-How-Accurate-is-IE7-IE8-Emulation&s=7727dfed209d8303df7ec6c08965ccdc&p=4716641&viewfull=1#post4716641). I will keep looking for a solution. Thanks so much for your time!